# Error in SQL Syntax

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to database in Java. It's a simple program.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/servlets","root","");
smt = con.createStatement();
query = "select pass from users where uname = "+uname;
System.out.println(query);
rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
if((rs.getString("pass"))==pass){
    out.println("correct pass...logged in..");
}
else {
    out.println("Incorrect pass...not logged in..");
}
```

But it says

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com'
>   at line 1

I am trying to verify the password for a particular email-id.

Comment: CHAR args have to be quoted with `'` or use bind parameters. Also, that's not how you check `String` equality.

Comment: You should escape `uname` with quotes in the query, or better yet, use `PreparedStatement` .

Comment: Your next question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this line

```
query = "select pass from users where uname = "+uname;
```

You have not quoted the `uname`, so if the value is `name@gmail.com` this results in a syntax error.  I.e. the actual statement being sent to the DB is

```
select pass from users where uname = name@gmail.com
```

which is invalid.  You should be using `PreparedStatement` instead

```
query = "select pass from users where uname = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,uname);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I know you probably just wanted to keep it simple, but if you need to teach about `PreparedStatement`, you should use the opportunity to also teach the use of try-with-resources. It doesn't really extend the example much, and it will lead readers in the right direction, preempting the next question about why resources get exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
        query = "select pass from users where uname = "+uname;
```

to

```
       query = "select pass from users where uname = "'+uname+'"  ";
```

or  try

```
            query = "select pass from users where uname = ? ";
```

Comment: I see absolutely *no* good reason that OP query should not be using prepared statements with bind placeholders. We don't have any information about whether the contents of `uname` (the return from `uname.toString()` ) is verified to be *safe* to include in SQL text... "oh yes Little Bobby Tables we call him"... we cannot in good conscience recommend wrapping `uname` in single quotes and including it as part of the SQL text. (Perhaps the suggestion in this answer, adding single quotes outside of the string literals (what?) is an sly way of suggesting that this is *not* the right approach.)